# Android studio Music player: Cannot open app

Tags: android, android-music-player

I am trying to make a music player with play and pause button. When I run the app, the emulator can't open the app.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    ImageButton pauseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;



    public  void play (View view) {

        mediaPlayer.start();

        playButton.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(0);
        pauseButton.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(0);

    }

    public  void pause (View view) {

        mediaPlayer.pause();

        playButton.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(0);
        pauseButton.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(0);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wishyouweregay);

    }
}
```

Comment: we need more information. can you post the logcat? and have you tried to run it on a real device?

Comment: Try moving the "findviewbyid" to onCreate and leave the private button where they are

Comment: private ImageButton playButton; then in onCreate() playButton = findViewById...